# How feasible is this query

Tags: mongodb

suppose you have a collection of documents with the following structure:

```
_id
A_id = ObjectId
B_id = ObjectId
C_id = ObjectId
+ other stuff
```

suppose you have a collection of roughly 100 million to 1 billion documents. I have to run a query,
which returns all documents such that A_id, B_id, or C_id are in some list of ObjectId, say L = [ ObjectId]

Something like this:

```
{ '$or' : [ { 'A_id' : { '$in' : L}},
{ 'B_id' : { '$in' : L}},
{ 'C_id' : { '$in' : L}} ]
}
```

Q: is it doable to run such query? Is it normal to run such queries on mongodb?
Q: how long can it take of a single server and how long may it take at horizontally scaled database?

Comment: What are your indexes?

Comment: Can we have so more info on what you are trying to accomplish? This doc structure with three objids seems really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

It is a doable query.

The real question is *"is it a good query?"*

The answer to that question is extremely dependant upon many variables.

First off I am assuming you have an index on each of the fields you are querying. I am also assuming that the query stands as is, without a sort. It should be noted that there are problems which stop a sort index from being used here by the optimiser: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1205

Assuming you have indexes on `A_id`, `B_id` and `C_id` MongoDB will essentially do 3 queries and merge duplicates before returning your result.

This means that for small `$or` queries it might be faster within the database (or `mongos`) itself since you don't have to merge duplicates yourself in your application which not only spares network traffic but also costly iteration of the results of each clause of the `$or`.

So for a small `$or` like that the query is Okay. It isn't the best query in the world but it will do if you have no choice but to do an `$or`.

> Q: how long can it take of a single server and how long may it take at horizontally scaled database?

Not sure if anyone here can answer that. It depends upon schema, the size of the `$in`s and much more.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly doable to run that query. However, you might want to consider an alternative structure that could be more easily searched.

Instead of

```
_id
A_id = ObjectId
B_id = ObjectId
C_id = ObjectId
+ other stuff
```

You might want to restructure it to be:

```
_id
idList = [ 
   { k: 'A', v: AObjectId },
   { k: 'B', v: BObjectId },
   { k: 'C', v: CObjectId }
]
+ other stuff
```

By using an array, with sub-objects with a `key` and `value` field, you can index the `value` fields so you can do just a single efficient query:

```
{ 'idList' : { $in : [listToCheck] } }
```